# Rails 3 remote form not triggering callback

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ajax, forms, jquery

I have a remote form that is populated by jQuery with an AJAX request. Then, I am binding this form to an AJAX callback but the callback is not being triggered.

```
var msgSuccess=function(evt, data, status, xhr){
  alert('ok!!!');
  console.log(evt);
  console.log(data);
  console.log(status);
  console.log(xhr);
}

var bindMsg = function() {   // BIND IT TO THE CALLBACKS
  $("#composeMsgPopup")
  .live('ajax:beforeSend', loadingCallback)
  .live('ajax:success', msgSuccess)
  .live('ajax:error', failureCallback)
  .live('ajax:complete',completeCallback);
}

$.ajax({      // GETTING THE FORM CODE
  url: link,
  type: "get",
  success: function(response, textStatus, jqXHR) {
    ans=response;
    $("#popup_content").html(ans);
    $("#popup").bPopup();
    bindMsg();
  },
  error: function(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) {
    failureCallback(errorThrown, textStatus, jqXHR);
  },
  complete: function(jqXHR, textStatus) {
    completeCallback("", jqXHR, textStatus);
  },
  beforeSend: loadingCallback
});
```

The code for the form:

```
<%= form_for(:conversation, :remote => true, 
 :url=> {:controller=>:conversations,:action=>:create},
 :html=>{:id => 'composeMsgPopup' }) do |f| %>
<div id="founder-name" class="field"><b>Recipient: <%= @user.name %></b></div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :subject,"Subject" %>
  <%= f.text_field :subject,:class=>"composeMsgField" %>
</div>
<div class="field">
  <%= f.label :content,"Message Content" %>
  <%= f.text_area :content,:class=>"composeMsgField" %>
</div>
<%= f.hidden_field :to_user, :value => @user.id  %>
<%= f.submit "Send", :class=>"submitbt",:id=>'sendMessage' %>
<% end % >
```

I have tried to bind with bind() or on() but it does not work. The code is executed but when I submit the form the callback is not executed.

Comment: why are you calling bindMsg() in the AJAX success part? The AJAX request is asynchronous and I don't think that it will work at all, when you call bindMsg() that late. And additionally, I don't think you need to extract that code to bindMsg() at all. Try to put the code directly into the success part of the AJAX call. You can refactor it out later - after everything works ...

Comment: and i need the bind because the form code is in the ajax response

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ok i found a solution.
the remote form not triggering the callback for unknown reason, so what i did is change the
submit button behaviour:

```
     <%= f.button :submit, "Update",:class=>"submitbt",:id=>"submitnewpass",:onclick=>"return false;" %>
```

and bind the button to manually submit the form

```
 var action=$('#composeMsgPopup')[0].action;   // action url
$("#sendMessage").click(function() {         // bind submit button

    $.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: action,
        data: $("#submitnewpass").serialize(), // serializes the form's elements.
        success: function(data)
        {
           // do my stuff

        },
        error:      failureCallback,
        beforeSend: loadingCallback,
        complete:   completeCallback
    });

    return false;
});
```